# How to build a model using multiple features in Tensorflow Federated?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I have the following codes and problem when trying to create OrderedDict for multiple feature inputs (i.e., features a-g) and one label h.

```
def preprocess(dataset):

  def batch_format_fn(element):

    return collections.OrderedDict(
        x=collections.OrderedDict(
            a=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None,], dtype=tf.int32),
            b=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None,], dtype=tf.int32),
            c=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None,], dtype=tf.int32),
            d=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None,], dtype=tf.int32),
            e=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None,], dtype=tf.int32),
            f=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None,], dtype=tf.int32),
            g=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None,], dtype=tf.int32)),
        y=tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None,], dtype=tf.int32))
  return dataset.map(batch_format_fn).prefetch(PREFETCH_BUFFER)

preprocessed_sample_dataset = preprocess(example_dataset)

def create_keras_model():
    model = Sequential([
    feature_layer,
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax') #classification 3 outputs
    ])
    return model

def model_fn():

  keras_model = create_keras_model()
  return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
      keras_model,
      input_spec=preprocessed_sample_dataset.element_spec,
      loss=losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
```

It shows an error like this when executing `input_spec=preprocessed_sample_dataset.element_spec`:

```
TypeError: Unsupported return value from function passed to Dataset.map(): OrderedDict([('x', OrderedDict([('a', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), ('b', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), ('c', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), ('d', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), ('e', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), ('f', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), ('g', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))])), ('y', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))]).
```

I have read this alternative [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61458419/solved-tensorflow-federated-tff-learning-from-keras-model-with-a-model-wit), however it is not clear how to implement it in my case. Hence, how to correctly assign ordered dict for the multiple features in TFF?

The current example_dataset.element_spec is as follows:

```
OrderedDict([
('a', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), 
('b', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), 
('c', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), 
('d', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), 
('e', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), 
('f', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), 
('g', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), 
('y', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))])
```

I want the element_spec becomes like this:

```
OrderedDict([('x', OrderedDict([
('a', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), 
('b', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), 
('c', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), 
('d', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), 
('e', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), 
('f', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)), 
('g', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))])), 
('y', TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))])
```

How to make the element_spec as the latter one using the batch_format_fn?

Comment: Looking at `batch_format_fn`, it looks like the return value is independent of the argument `element`; I suspect you would get the same error if you simply iterated over the dataset. Perhaps the returned `OrderedDict` should reshape `element`?

Comment: @KeithRush how the returned OrderedDict can reshape element?

Comment: Can give an expanded answer below, but can you update the question with the `element_spec` property of `example_dataset`? I believe we will need this to understand how to change

Comment: @KeithRush I have updated the question with the ```element_spec```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`batch_format_fn` currently returns a structure of tensor *types*; `tf.data.Dataset.map` expects to receive a structure of *tensors* as the return value of the function.

We should update `batch_format_fn` to reformat its `element` argument and return that instead. Let's try something like:

```
def batch_format_fn(element):
  feature_dict = collections.OrderedDict(
      a=element['a'],
      b=element['b'],
      c=element['c'],
      d=element['d'],
      e=element['e'],
      f=element['f'],
      g=element['g'],
  )
  return collections.OrderedDict(x=feature_dict, y=element['y'])
```

and keeping everything else the same.

Comment: I have updated my question again. The current element_spec is missing ```('x', OrderedDict([```. I want the current ```element_spec``` is the same as the ```input_spec``` to make it work. Actually, I try to use batch_format_fn(self) but the same error still happens. How to bypass it? As I need to include ```.map(batch_format_fn)```